# Application Crashes With No Exception

Tags: c#, winforms, ffmpeg

Have a relatively complex C# Windows Forms application that makes use of C++ bridge DLL to call FFmpeg DLLS to concurrently write multiple MP4 files directly from imagery downloaded from real time cameras using a separate thread for each camera.

On my Windows 7 development laptop, Toshiba Tecra with i7 vPro eight core CPU and 16GB RAM, and on customer laptop, application runs fine.
But on customer desktop, configuration unknown, when the application finishes recording and begins downloading imagery from the real time cameras and thus begins calling FFmpeg DLLs, the application disappears without a trace, no exception message, no "program has stopped working", nothing. Normal program exit writes an "application exiting" message to a log file which is NOT happening, so I am reasonably certain the program is not normally exiting.
What might result in a C# Windows Forms application crash with no exception report from Windows?

Comment: try running procmon to watch whats happening

Comment: Did you check the machine's event logs?

Comment: In this case, sometimes, packing debug/trace and use debug viewer from sysinternal, can help

Comment: @pm100 Good idea, but unfortunately the problem machine is in one state and I am in another. I have, however, discovered "unhandled exceptions", which can cause the gone-without-a-trace events that I am advised of. I'm going to follow the advice at this link:http://blog.functionalfun.net/2013/05/how-to-debug-silent-crashes-in-net.html

Comment: Problem was an unhandled exception. Once I put the below code into my app, it was revealed that a certain DLL was "not found", although of course the DLL file is more certainly right there in the same folder as the EXE. And the DLL, which I wrote, does not link to any other DLL, though it does LoadLibrary on the FFmpeg DLLs.
AppDomain currentDomain = AppDomain.CurrentDomain;
currentDomain.UnhandledException += new UnhandledExceptionEventHandler(MyHandler);